# How to apply two check boxes separately for "Terms or Use" and "Privacy policy" in B2C Sign up page (using custom policy)

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

i have implemented the "terms of use" consent checkbox following the gitHub resource [Term Of Use CheckBox](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-sign-up-versioned-tou)
this sample demonstrates one check box implementation for "Terms of Use" only. which i have implemented perfectly, but i want to add one more check box for "Privacy policy" also very similar to "Terms of Use". as the requirement is, both can be updated independently, when User sign in they need to reconsent for which ever is updated . and if both (TOU and Privacy Policy) are updated the user should re consent for both on a same page.

i am a bit confused on the OrchestrationStep for doing the above scenario.
any light on above issue will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want both checkboxes on your "consent" screen you must add 2 output claims in Technical Profile. To achieve the goal where you display "consent" screen if any of the consents requires re-consenting requires few steps. First of all use claims transformation [AndClaims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/boolean-transformations#andclaims) to produce the proper result and place it in let's say tosConsented. Use it as OutputClaimsTransformation in technical profile responsible for reading consents state claims. Having that claim you can just add a simple precondition to your orchestration step responsible for showing "consents" screen:

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
      <Value>tosConsented</Value>
      <Value>true</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
     <ClaimsExchange Id="MyConsentsScreen" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="MyConsentsScreen" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your response, can you tell please how to check is Privacy consent required  against a specific date and time?  for "Privacy Policy" I replicated the same steps used for "Term of Use" provided in the above mentions sample but it failed to upload the policy with errors that TransformationMethod not supported for Privacy policy. i want to check each document consent dateTime and which ever is updated display reconsent screen(with its check box) for that, and if both are updated then display reconsent for both(both check boxes).

Comment: I've been there recently. If you store consents state in AAD then you can add date attributes for each consent. The other way, the way I've chosen recently is to create consents management API that handles what you need. Make the API more general that can handle more consents in a future and pass consents as a string list claim.

Answer (score 0):

•   You can do this by creating a new version of your terms of use and modify the version (date or number) in the custom policy users to required, on the next login, to agree to those new terms of use again. For this, ensure to enter your tenant’s name to the header of all files in the Local Account template. And create a custom attribute by using the default ‘b2c-extensions-app’ with the custom policy.

•   When creating the custom attribute with the name ‘TemsOfUseConsented’ of type string, edit the ‘TrustFrameworkBase.xml’ file and add the claimtype to the section 3 of the claim’s schema block. After doing this, add the ContentDefinition block in the xml file and then tell the policy where the extension attributes are located by entering the GUIDs of the b2c-extension-app in the policy.

•   Then read the stored consent attribute from the directory by locating the technical profile ID and adding an additional output claim. So, when this reads the attribute every time, the user is searched and read from the directory and stores it in the output claim. Then create the technical profile to write the consent attribute to AAD and this profile will be used later as validation technical profile to store the consent attribute if the user agrees to the terms of use.

•   Once done, create the custom user journey in TrustFrameworkExtension.xml file and then switch the new journey as the default journey. After this, switch to signuporsignin.xml file and modify the custom user journey to default one. Load all the policies one by one in the B2C tenant and then create new version of your terms of use to edit the date values in claim types and the preconditions of the user journey in TrustFrameWorkExtension. In this way, you can add the user sign in reconsent page. Please find the below orchestration code for user journey below for your reference: -

```
  <UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignIn-withConsent">
    <OrchestrationSteps>

<OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" 
  ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
  <ClaimsProviderSelections>
    <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
  </ClaimsProviderSelections>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>

<OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
      <Value>objectId</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>

<!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when in the token. -->
<OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>

 <!-- execute consent step if the users consented version does not met the current version,
      otherwhise this step is skipped -->
<OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
      <Value>extension_TermsOfUseConsented</Value>
      <Value>2018-09-15</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAssertedConsentExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Consent" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>

<OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />

  </OrchestrationSteps>
 <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
  </UserJourney>
```